# Openssl rsautl output to base64

Tags: bash, encryption, rsa

I have this command within a shell script

`echo -n $2 | openssl rsautl -encrypt -pubin -inkey $1`

where `$2` stands for a string argument and `$1` is the public key that is to be used.

I would like the output to be the equivalent base64 string of the binary encryption, but adding `| base64` at the end of the command does not seem to work (probably because the encrypted output contains null characters and cuts the base64 input short.

Is it possible to accomplish the base64 encoding without creating a cyphertext intermediary file to dump the data in the first place?

For example, I would like to make

`echo -n "asdf" | openssl rsautl -encrypt -pubin -inkey key.pub.pem`

to output something along the lines of

> stWslUhRRCk/bZveABLG7fA8z9ZkYc+lBBd5QhvyGNwuI2T5v2sk8aJL3X3Xerrogsu35Wk5O839..........

**instead of binary unreadable characters** without requiring an intermediate file to be created (I truncated the output for brevity)

Comment: Can you be a bit more clear? The output of `openssl rsautl -encrypt -pubin -inkey $1` has null characters? can you show us some sample values?

Comment: The command you mentioned outputs a binary value representing the encrypted message. It is likely that within that output, a byte is equal to `\0` and be interpreted as a null terminator by bash when it writes to variables or towards `base64`. I'll try and clarify above.

Comment: So what is your requirment? Can you show  a sample value and an expected output you need for it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, I have to state that I could not reproduce your problem, it is probably dependent on the bash version.

I am aware of two ways to pass the output of `openssl rsautl` to base64 without piping stdout and using a file.

## Bash process substitution

Bash is able to directly pass the output of an operation to some command while the program believes, it is writing the output to a file.

```
echo "foo"|openssl rsautl -encrypt -pubin -inkey key -out >(base64)
```

## Named Pipes

You can create a *named pipe* usign the `mkfifo` command and then use that, as if it was a file.

```
mkfifo /tmp/mypipe
echo "foo" | openssl rsautl -encrypt -pubin -inkey key -out /tmp/mypipe &
base64 /tmp/mypipe
rm /tmp/mypipe
```

Comment: Your Bash process substitution command is what I have been looking for (even though it asks for a private key to encrypt). I wanted to have a one liner that does exactly that. Encrypts data into a base64 encoded string. I didn't know that I could redirect the output to another command by placing it in parentheses (so it wouldn't create a file named base64). I initially tried using `| base64` instead of `> (base64)` and it didn't work, hence my question.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "foo" | openssl rsautl -encrypt -inkey rsa_key.pub -pubin | openssl base64
```

the openssl base64 will take the binary encrypted code as an input and produces the base64 that is the human-readable format.